# Referencing temporary, unsaved workbook when copying worksheets

Tags: excel, vba, object, copy

I have worksheets I want to copy to a new, temporary workbook -- **without saving it**.

`Worksheet.Copy` copies the worksheet to a new, unnamed'ish (Book1, Book2, Book3, etc) workbook. I want all sheets to be copied to the same workbook.

For all worksheets after the first, I have tried using `Worksheet.Copy After:=xlWb.Sheets(1)`, but I do not know how to reference the newly created workbook when setting the xlWb workbook-object. I keep receiving

> run-time error 9, 'Subscript out of range'.

```
Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
Dim xlWb As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWbOld As String
Dim xlWs As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlWbNew As Excel.Workbook
Dim xlWsOld As Excel.Worksheet
Dim xlRng As Excel.Range
Dim xlRngOld As Excel.Range

xlWbOld = ActiveWorkbook.Name

Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
xlApp.Visible = True                                '*** Quite Important to set Excel.Visible,_
                                                    'Otherwise user wouldn't see the application's running _
                                                    'even though it would run as background

xlApp.Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set xlWb = xlApp.Workbooks.Add                      'Create a new Workbook
Set xlWs = xlWb.Worksheets.Add
```

And this is where the worksheets should be copied:

```
Select Case strRptType
    Case "DAILY"
        xlWs.Name = "1-Daily Price"
        'Check the last column and the last row
        lLastRow = oBasic.GetLast(, "DailyRpt", False, "A")
        iLastCol = oBasic.GetLast(, "DailyRpt", True, 4)
        Set xlRngOld = wksDailyRpt.Range(wksDailyRpt.Cells(4, 1), wksDailyRpt.Cells(lLastRow, iLastCol))
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        xlRngOld.Copy

        Set xlRng = xlWs.Cells(1, 1)
        xlRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        xlWs.Columns.AutoFit

        For Each xlWsOld In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
            If xlWsOld.Name = "ForwardPrices" Or xlWsOld.Name = "ForwardVolatilities" _
              Or xlWsOld.Name = "ForwardReturns" Or xlWsOld.Name = "ForwardCorrelations" Then

                Sheets(xlWsOld.Name).Copy After:=Workbooks(xlWb).Sheets(1)

            End If
        Next xlWsOld
End Select
```

Comment: Have you tried macro-recorder? You may also need `Workbooks` collection members to obtain newly created workbook name.

Comment: Show us how you are creating the Workbook.

Comment: I added some code snippets showing how the Workbook is created and how I would like to copy the worksheets.

Comment: For a start, change `Sheets(xlWsOld.Name).Copy After:=Workbooks(xlWb).Sheets(1)` to `xlWsOld.Copy After:=xlWb.Sheets(1)` - sorry, don't have time right now to investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with the following:

```
            For Each xlWsOld In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
                If xlWsOld.Name = "ForwardPrices" Or xlWsOld.Name = "ForwardVolatilities" _
                Or xlWsOld.Name = "ForwardReturns" Or xlWsOld.Name = "ForwardCorrelations" Then

                    Set xlRngOld = Nothing
                    Set xlWsForwards = xlWb.Worksheets.Add

                    lLastRow = oBasic.GetLast(, xlWsOld.Name, False, "A")
                    iLastCol = oBasic.GetLast(, xlWsOld.Name, True, 1)

                    Set xlRngOld = xlWsOld.Range(xlWsOld.Cells(1, 1), xlWsOld.Cells(lLastRow, iLastCol))

                    xlWsForwards.Name = xlWsOld.Name
                    xlRngOld.Copy
                    Set xlRngForwards = xlWsForwards.Cells(1, 1)
                    xlRngForwards.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
                    xlWsForwards.Columns.AutoFit

                    xlWsForwards.Cells(1, 1).Select

                    Set xlWsForwards = Nothing

                End If
            Next xlWsOld
```

Answer (score 1):

This little macro goes through all the sheets of all the open workbooks, and copies them after the current sheet.

```
Sub GatherAllSheets()
  Dim Wb As Workbook, Sh As Worksheet
  For Each Wb In Workbooks
    If Not Wb Is ThisWorkbook Then
      For Each Sh In Wb.Worksheets
        Sh.Copy after:=ActiveSheet
      Next Sh
    End If
  Next Wb
End Sub
```

Is this what you need?
Or you need to copy the content of the sheets on the same sheet?

Comment: I have one workbook containing 10 sheets. Of those 10, I want to copy 5 to a new, temporary workbook. I might be able to adapt your code to my needs tomorrow, by running the For-loop after the temporary workbook has been created and adding some `If Worksheet.Name = x` checks along the way to make sure only the desired worksheets are copied to the new workbook. I'm worried, though, that your solution won't work unless these two are the only workbooks open, which isn't something I can demand of the users.

Comment: Update: The temporary workbook does not seem to be a member of Workbooks, so I cannot reference it this way either.

Comment: To consider only some workbooks you can use the same technique: `If Wb.Name = "X"`, or `If Wb.Sheet(1).Cells(1, 1) = "Y"`, where X and Y are some known value that helps identify the sheets/workbooks to copy. In my example the temporary workbook is the one active when the macro starts. I assumed your macro would create it before running this cycle. All the workbooks of one Excel instance are part of the Workbooks collection. Why do you say your temporary one is not?

Answer (score 0):

skip creating the new workbook, and copy all the sheets in one go.

```
xlWbOld.Sheets(Array("ForwardPrices", "ForwardVolatilities", "ForwardReturns", "ForwardCorrelations")).Copy
Set xlWb = ActiveWorkbook
```

this way copying creates the new workbook which becomes ActiveWorkbook. then you can assign it to a workbook object, and reference it by that name later on